# SQL ORA- 12560: TNS: protocol adapter error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

While installing **Oracle 10g** I'm getting this error.
How to rectify this error during Installation?
[image: Error TNS protocol adapter]

Comment: The database service probably didn't start. Oracle 10g is *ancient* and no longer supported. What Windows version are you installing on?

Comment: windows 10 @pmdba

Comment: That won't work. From what I can tell, you would need to go all the way back to Windows Vista to have support for 10g. Why not use a current version of the database, like the 18c Express Edition or 19c, if you want to run on a current operating system?

Comment: No for some PC it's getting installing, error is occurring to only my pc @pmdba

Comment: It's not a supported operating system for 10g, and 10g hasn't been a supported database version for close to 10 years. Your results will not be predictable. Why use such old software and not a current version?